# C# ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

My query will execute the first time in a switch case loop, but during the second case nothing happens with it

everything is written inside of a for loop, it manages to add the first query into the database properly but after that it doesn't

```
string sQuery = string.Format("'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}',{7},'{8}','{9}',{10}", sName, sMiddleName, sSurname, sBirthdate, sSex, sNationality, sDateOfArrival, sCardID, sUsername, sPassword, sPhoneNumber);
SqlConnection cnn;

cnn = new SqlConnection(Globals.sqlConnect);
cnn.Open();
SqlCommand command;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
String sql = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Refugee ([Name],[Middlename],[Surname],[Birthdate],[Sex],[Nationality],[Date_of_arrival],[ID_Card_Number],[Username],[Password],[Phone_Number]) VALUES(" + sQuery + ")";

            command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
            adapter.InsertCommand = command;
            adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.Dispose();
            break;
        case 1:
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.HoF == true)
            {
            sQuery = string.Format("'{0}' ,{1}",Properties.Settings.Default.Familyname,tb_cardID);
            sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Family ([Family_name],[Head_Of_Family_ID_Card_Number]) VALUES ("+ sQuery +")";

                command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

                adapter.InsertCommand = command;
                adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.Dispose();
            }

            break;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200536/discussion-on-question-by-lekerkiii-c-executenonquery).

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't know where the values for the parameters came from I just assumed they were passed into the procedure. You need to check the datatypes of the of the parameters in your database and change the code accordingly. Convert the values to matching types. `using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. Using parameters protects you form Sql injection.

The loop ,switch and dataadapter are unnecessary.

```
    private void OPCode(string sName,string sMiddleName,string sSurname,DateTime sBirthdate,string sSex,string sNationality,DateTime sDateOfArrival,int sCardID,string sUsername,string sPassword,string sPhoneNumber, int tb_cardID)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Globals.sqlConnect))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Refugee ([Name],[Middlename],[Surname],[Birthdate],[Sex],[Nationality],[Date_of_arrival],[ID_Card_Number],[Username],[Password],[Phone_Number]) VALUES (@sName, @sMiddleName, @sSurname, @sBirthdate, @sSex, @sNationality, @sDateOfArrival, @sCardID, @sUsername, @sPassword, @sPhoneNumber);", cnn))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@sName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sMiddleName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sMiddleName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sSurname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sSurname;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sBirthdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = sBirthdate;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sSex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sSex;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sNationality", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sNationality;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sDateOfArrival", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = sDateOfArrival;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sCardID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sCardID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sUsername", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sUsername;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sPassword;
                command.Parameters.Add("@sPhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sPhoneNumber;
                cnn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } //disposes command
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.HoF == true)
            {
                using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Family ([Family_name],[Head_Of_Family_ID_Card_Number]) VALUES (@FamilyName, @tb_carID;", cnn))
                { 
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Familyname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Properties.Settings.Default.Familyname;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@tb_cardID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tb_cardID; 
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }//disposes second command
            }
        }//closes and disposes connection
    }
```